# karma test on angular 2 ag grid 'exports is not defined'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

Hey all I'm trying to test my table component that is a wrapper on the old and good ag grid.

I added the path to karma.conf.js  `'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/main.js'`
Also I added the ag grid component in the test file:
`import { RgGridComponent } from "../../shared/grid-control/grid-control.component";
import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
...
...
 declarations: [TracesTableComponent, RgGridComponent, AgGridNg2],`

But when I try to run the test I get the message : "exports is not defined"
I can really use some help. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer! I needed to install @types/jasmine and then import it like this:  `import { } from 'jasmine';`